# ListLinePlot not showing filling

Tags: plotting

My code is

```
ListLinePlot[{
    {{0, 185}, {-10, 187}, {-20, 186}, {-30, 158}, {-40, 159}, {-60, 116}}, 
    {{0, 155}, {-10, 132}, {-20, 165}, {-30, 112}, {-40, 85}, {-60, 95}}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Why doesn't `Filling` work on my plot?

Comment: Perhaps it's just a sanity check. `ListLinePlot[Transpose@{{3, 4, 6, 5, 7, 8}, {2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2}}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 3}, Filling -> Axis]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, this is more a long comment than a full answer. It seems to me that it is struggling with the fact that you (1.) supply x-coordinate in (2.) decreasing/"unsorted" order. Sorting it fixes it, try:

```
ListLinePlot[{
    Sort@{{0, 185}, {-10, 187}, {-20, 186}, {-30, 158}, {-40, 159}, {-60, 116}}, 
    Sort@{{0, 155}, {-10, 132}, {-20, 165}, {-30, 112}, {-40, 85}, {-60, 95}}}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

Alternatively, in your case (of strictly decreasing x-coords), you could use `Reverse`.

For the "Why?", I do not know, maybe somebody else can help? (I cannot see a word on that in `ListLinePlot` documentation, in particular in the possible issues section)

Comment: I note that you specify the Filling option differently than the OP. Any reason for that?

Comment: Good eyes! I was playing around a bit with other things and trying out stuff, forgot to change back. `{1->{2}}` and `{2->{1}}` shouldn't change a thing. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: See ["Unordered data may display in unexpected ways"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html#1286575289)

Comment: Note that a version of this bug persists even when the data is sorted: [[97181](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97181/bug-in-listlineplot-when-filling-up-and-down?noredirect=1&lq=1)].