# Bug in ListLinePlot[] when Filling up and down?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, bugs, filling

**Bug introduced in 9.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later**

---

I'm trying to understand this apparently incorrect `Filling` behavior in `ListLinePlot[]`.  Evaluating this

```
Table[ListLinePlot[
 {{{-6.62, -25.469}, {-6.59, y}},{{-6.62, -25.55}, {-6.57, -25.7}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.01], PlotRange -> {{-6.63, -6.52}, {-25.8, -25.4}},
 ImageSize -> 500, Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {Green, Red}}}
], {y, {-25.68, -25.72}}]
```

produces this:
[image]

The `Filling` option is supposed to be filling green above the orange line and red below it, but this breaks when one slightly adjusts the y-value of the endpoint of the blue line so that it is above the endpoint of the orange line.

This issue also exists in `ListPlot[]` using the `Joined->True` option.  I'm using Mathematica 10.3.0.0.

I suspect this is related to [the problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95973/filling-option-failing-when-listlineplot-given-my-data) [with needing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html#1286575289) [to sort the data points](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/G3gob_Mw9sQ) for `Filling` to work.  (Otherwise, it fails silently, which is horrendously confusing for beginners.)  However, in this case, there are only two points for each line, and they are sorted. I haven't been able to figure out exactly what's going on, and what to do to avoid it. It may also be related to [this apparent bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92763/listlineplot-filling-wrong), but there don't seem to be any new points created.

**EDIT:** Here is a slightly more minimal example, thanks to george2079, confirming that this is not just another example of the ordering problem.

```
Table[ ListLinePlot[ 
 {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{.2, 0}, {.8, y}, {1, .5}}}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {Green, Red}}}
], {y, {.9, 1.1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag until your observations have been confirmed by other users.

Comment: OK, got it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: This may be relevant: [30145](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30145/listlineplot-not-showing-filling/30148#30148)

Comment: In your second case you have reversed the ordering of the lines (introducing the known sorting issue )

Comment: The first case is *not* ordering related.  Here is another example `Table[
 ListLinePlot[  {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{.2, 0}, {.8, y}, {1, .5}}}, 
  Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {Green, Red}}}], {y, {.9, 1.1}}]`

Comment: OK, good point george.  I'll replace my second example with yours.