# Filling between two listplots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two lists which are plotted by below simple command

```
ListPlot[{{{0.`, 0.001`}, {0.05`, 0.04`}, {0.1`, 
0.076`}, {0.15000000000000002`, 0.115`}, {0.2`, 0.151`}, {0.25`, 
0.19`}, {0.30000000000000004`, 0.226`}, {0.35000000000000003`, 
0.265`}, {0.4`, 0.301`}, {0.45`, 0.34`}, {0.5`, 0.376`}, {0.55`, 
0.41500000000000004`}, {0.6000000000000001`, 0.454`}, {0.65`, 
0.49`}, {0.7000000000000001`, 0.529`}, {0.75`, 
0.5650000000000001`}, {0.8`, 0.604`}, {0.8500000000000001`, 
0.64`}, {0.9`, 0.679`}, {0.9500000000000001`, 0.715`}, {1.`, 
0.754`}, {1.05`, 0.79`}, {1.1`, 
0.8290000000000001`}, {1.1500000000000001`, 
0.865`}, {1.2000000000000002`, 0.904`}, {1.25`, 
0.9400000000000001`}, {1.3`, 0.979`}, {1.35`, 
1.015`}, {1.4000000000000001`, 
1.0539999999999998`}, {1.4500000000000002`, 1.093`}, {1.5`, 
1.129`}, {1.55`, 1.168`}, {1.6`, 1.204`}, {1.6500000000000001`, 
1.2429999999999999`}, {1.7000000000000002`, 1.279`}, {1.75`, 
1.3179999999999998`}, {1.8`, 1.3539999999999999`}, {1.85`, 
1.393`}, {1.9000000000000001`, 
1.4289999999999998`}, {1.9500000000000002`, 1.468`}, {2.`, 
1.504`}}, {{0.`, 0.001`}, {0.05`, 0.037000000000000005`}, {0.1`, 
0.07300000000000001`}, {0.15000000000000002`, 0.106`}, {0.2`, 
0.14200000000000002`}, {0.25`, 0.178`}, {0.30000000000000004`, 
0.211`}, {0.35000000000000003`, 0.247`}, {0.4`, 
0.28300000000000003`}, {0.45`, 0.319`}, {0.5`, 
0.35200000000000004`}, {0.55`, 0.388`}, {0.6000000000000001`, 
0.424`}, {0.65`, 0.46`}, {0.7000000000000001`, 0.493`}, {0.75`, 
0.529`}, {0.8`, 0.5650000000000001`}, {0.8500000000000001`, 
0.598`}, {0.9`, 0.634`}, {0.9500000000000001`, 0.67`}, {1.`, 
0.706`}, {1.05`, 0.739`}, {1.1`, 0.775`}, {1.1500000000000001`, 
0.811`}, {1.2000000000000002`, 0.844`}, {1.25`, 0.88`}, {1.3`, 
0.916`}, {1.35`, 0.9520000000000001`}, {1.4000000000000001`, 
0.985`}, {1.4500000000000002`, 1.021`}, {1.5`, 1.057`}, {1.55`, 
1.093`}, {1.6`, 1.126`}, {1.6500000000000001`, 
1.162`}, {1.7000000000000002`, 1.198`}, {1.75`, 
1.2309999999999999`}, {1.8`, 1.267`}, {1.85`, 
1.303`}, {1.9000000000000001`, 1.339`}, {1.9500000000000002`, 
1.3719999999999999`}, {2.`, 1.408`}}}]
```

I want to have a plot as 
[image]

filling between two list plots drawn by my self. How do I apply `filling` between any two `Listplots`?

Comment: Beware filling between discrete data points in `ListPlot`: ([97181](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97181/bug-in-listlineplot-when-filling-up-and-down)) ([30145](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30145/listlineplot-not-showing-filling/30148#30148)) ([G3gob_Mw9sQ](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/G3gob_Mw9sQ)).  At the very least, make sure the data is sorted (but there can still be issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l1 = Range[30];
l2 = 1.05 Range[30];

Show[ListLinePlot[{l1, l2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
  FillingStyle -> Magenta, PlotStyle -> Magenta],
 ListPlot[{l1, l2}]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{l1, l2}, Mesh -> All, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Magenta]
```

[image]

Or with very thin lines and all disks.

```
ListPlot[{l1, l2}, Mesh -> All, 
 PlotMarkers -> {{"●", 10}, {"●", 10}}, 
 Joined -> True, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Magenta, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, if possible even short can you tell me about `Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, ` details of its duty. I can't understand mean of that! For example I try with `Filling-> True` it doesn't satisfy the main aim.

Comment: @Irreversible [Filling Limits documentation](http://www.reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html#396638).

Answer (score 3):

```
{l1, l2} = {{{0., 0.}, {0.05, 0.04}, {0.1, 0.08}, {0.15, 0.12}, {0.2, 0.15}, {0.25, 0.19}, 
            {0.3, 0.23}, {0.35, 0.26}, {0.4, 0.3}, {0.45, 0.34}, {0.5, 0.38}, 
            {0.55, 0.42}, {0.6, 0.45}, {0.65, 0.49}, {0.7, 0.53}, {0.75, 0.57}, 
            {0.8, 0.6}, {0.85, 0.64}, {0.9, 0.68}, {0.95,  0.72}, {1., 0.75}, 
            {1.05, 0.79}, {1.1, 0.83}, {1.15, 0.86}, 1.2, 0.9}, {1.25, 0.94}, 
            {1.3, 0.98}, {1.35, 1.01}, {1.4, 1.05}, {1.45, 1.09},{1.5, 1.13}, 
            {1.55, 1.17}, {1.6, 1.2}, {1.65, 1.24}, {1.7,   1.28}, {1.75, 1.32},
            {1.8, 1.35}, {1.85, 1.39}, {1.9, 1.43}, {1.95, 1.47}, {2., 1.5}}, 
           {{0., 0.}, {0.05, 0.04}, {0.1, 0.07}, {0.15, 0.11}, {0.2, 0.14},
            {0.25, 0.18}, {0.3, 0.21}, {0.35, 0.25}, {0.4, 0.28}, {0.45, 0.32}, 
            {0.5, 0.35}, {0.55, 0.39}, {0.6, 0.42}, {0.65, 0.46}, {0.7, 0.49}, 
            {0.75, 0.53}, {0.8, 0.57}, {0.85, 0.6}, {0.9, 0.63}, {0.95, 0.67}, 
            {1., 0.71}, {1.05, 0.74}, {1.1, 0.78}, {1.15, 0.81}, {1.2, 0.84}, 
            {1.25, 0.88}, {1.3, 0.92}, {1.35, 0.95}, {1.4, 0.98}, {1.45, 1.02}, 
            {1.5, 1.06}, {1.55, 1.09}, {1.6, 1.13}, {1.65, 1.16}, {1.7, 1.2}, 
            {1.75, 1.23}, {1.8, 1.27}, {1.85, 1.3}, {1.9,  1.34}, 
            {1.95, 1.37}, {2., 1.41}}};
```

You can repeat the lists and use the option `Joined`:

```
ListPlot[{l1, l2, l1, l2}, Joined -> {False, False, True, True} ,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, None, None}, 
 Filling -> {3 -> {{4}, Yellow}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Note** (thanks: Karsten7.): to get the default colors for the markers use `PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None}`.

Comment: `PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, None, None}` does create the default plot marker colors.

Comment: @Karsten7., good point, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If we call the two lists `l1` and `l2`, the thing that looks the most like what you have drawn can be made by turning the lists into `InterpolatingFunction`s using `Interpolation`, and then use the plot option `Filling`:

```
h1 = Interpolation[l1];
h2 = Interpolation[l2];
Plot[{h1[x], h2[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, FillingStyle -> Magenta]
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is excellent but I have to show the results are related to data not a function. In the final plot points replaced by lines. I have to show exactly by points.

Answer (score 2):

For such data you can also use `Prolog`:

```
ListPlot[{l1, l2}, 
 Prolog -> {Yellow, Polygon[Flatten[{l1, Reverse@l2}, 1]]}]
```