# filling between two listplot with unequal length

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have two sets of data :

```
data1 = {{0.36, 0.076}, {0.361, 0.075}, {0.362, 0.074}, {0.363, 
  0.072}, {0.364, 0.071}, {0.365, 0.069}, {0.366, 0.068}, {0.367, 
  0.066}, {0.368, 0.065}, {0.369, 0.063}, {0.37, 0.062}, {0.371, 
  0.06}, {0.372, 0.059}, {0.373, 0.057}, {0.374, 0.055}, {0.375, 
  0.053}, {0.376, 0.051}, {0.377, 0.049}, {0.378, 0.047}, {0.379, 
  0.045}, {0.38, 0.044}, {0.381, 0.042}, {0.382, 0.04}, {0.383, 
  0.038}, {0.384, 0.036}, {0.385, 0.034}, {0.386, 0.031}, {0.387, 
  0.029}, {0.388, 0.026}, {0.389, 0.022}, {0.39, 0.018}, {0.391, 
  0.012}, {0.392, 0.002}}
```

and

```
data2 = {{0.36, 0.076}, {0.361, 0.075}, {0.362, 0.074}, {0.363, 
  0.072}, {0.364, 0.071}, {0.365, 0.069}, {0.366, 0.068}, {0.367, 
  0.066}, {0.368, 0.065}, {0.369, 0.064}, {0.37, 0.062}, {0.371, 
  0.061}, {0.372, 0.059}, {0.373, 0.058}, {0.374, 0.056}, {0.375, 
  0.055}, {0.376, 0.054}, {0.377, 0.052}, {0.378, 0.051}, {0.379, 
  0.049}, {0.38, 0.048}, {0.381, 0.046}, {0.382, 0.045}, {0.383, 
  0.043}, {0.384, 0.041}, {0.385, 0.04}, {0.386, 0.038}, {0.387, 
  0.037}, {0.388, 0.036}, {0.389, 0.034}, {0.39, 0.033}, {0.391, 
  0.031}, {0.392, 0.029}, {0.393, 0.027}, {0.394, 0.025}, {0.395, 
  0.023}, {0.396, 0.021}, {0.397, 0.018}, {0.398, 0.014}, {0.399, 
  0.009}, {0.4, 0.002}}
```

I am going to make a list plot of these two sets of data and fill the area between them. I followed the instruction here :[Filling between two listplots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118256/filling-between-two-listplots), but i could not get the result I wanted. In what I get from listplot only a part of area is filled. How can I fill the remaining part?

By the way, the length of two sets of data is different

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

Use the suggestion by @J.M.'spersistentexhaustion `Prolog` instead of `Epilog`.

```
ListPlot[{data1, data2}, Joined -> True, Mesh -> All, 
 Prolog -> {Yellow, Polygon@Join[data1, Reverse@data2]}]
```

[image]

Comment: cvgmt surely knows this already, but for the OP: you can change `Epilog` to `Prolog` if you want the filling polygon to be placed *under* the plots you already had, instead of *over* like in this answer.